# Запретить доступ к несуществующим хостам в nginx

Tags: nginx, http, https

Ребята, помогите. Перерыл вы что можно, ничего не помогло :(И так: Есть домен (dom.com), пытаюсь сделать хосты 3-его уровня (xxx.dom.com, yyy.dom.com, zzz.dom.com), так же на будущее в bind добавлен еще одни хост: aaa.dom.comЕсть уже настроенный nginx на 3 хоста. Однако, если я ввиду в адресную строку aaa.dom.com, я попадаю на первый настроенный хост в nginx. Как запретить ему (nginx`у) отвечать на этот урл пока не появится настроенный хост?

Та же петрушка и с ип-адресом, но тут хотя бы логично, однако, хотелось бы, что бы я мог манипулировать такими вещами. Сделать первым хост, который хотелось бы что бы отображал при вводе ип-адреса?

Та же петрушка и в следующем: один из настроченных доменов 3-го уровня (zzz.dom.com) нужен для личного пользования и очень не хочется что бы адрес попал на глаза третьим лицам. Для него был сделан сертификат ssl и так же настроен в nginx, однако если в адресной строке набрать https://xxx.dom.com или https://yyy.dom.com nginx ищет первый настроенный ssl host и показывает его. Естественно браузер начинает ругаться, что ssl подписан для zzz.dom.com.

nginx 1.5.7

Comment: как хосты настроены?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Определите в конфиге nginx default_server и отдавайте там 403 на любой локейшен. <br>     [директива listen](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen)<br>[как nginx обрабатывает запросы](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/request_processing.html)
2. Манипулировать подобными вещами как раз поможет директива указанная выше.
3. Тут есть два пути решения проблемы:

   - Поднять дополнительный IP-адрес и повесить ssl-хост на него.
   - Использовать SNI<br>  [Конфигурация https-серверов](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html)